# Macbook Air strange boot-up

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I've searched before asking but couldn't find any related question with the problem that I'm facing.

I have a new Macbook Air (1 month) with Yosemite 10.10.1 that from the beginning is having some strange behavior on boot-up.

Specs:

- 1,7 GHz Intel Core i7
- 128 GB SSD
- 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB

When I press the power button the screen remains black (I notice a different black when the room is dark) for more than 1 minute before the apple logo appears and then it's seconds to go to the login screen.

**However, when I boot-up with the Alt key**, the screen to select the startup disk is very fast to appear and when I select the "Macintosh HD" disk, the Apple logo appears right away and then again it's seconds to go to the login screen.

So basically **if I boot with Alt key and force the disk, it is very fast to boot**. When I do a **"normal" boot, I have to wait at least 1 minute** before the Apple logo appears.

It seems to me like an hardware problem, but before I take the computer back to the store, I wanted to make sure if there is something else I should try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have an issue with settings stored in NVRAM. To reset your NVRAM to default settings (it's safe to do this), power on the system and simultaneously hold down the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> keys until you've heard not one, but TWO boot chimes. The second is usually louder. Then let them go.

If that doesn't fix things, then you should get test the hardware. That said, this tends to fix a lot of the slow-boot issues.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your suggestion. It seems that it's working ok (at least way faster) now!

Comment: Glad to hear it, Ricardo!

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a month old, you should still be within the full warranty window.  Have you taken it to a Genius Bar?